# Font Inconsistency in fncychap

Tags: fonts, chapters, books, fncychap

I am using the Sonny style for chapter headings in fncychap package. I noted that the font for chapter headings and the one for section headings are different. This seems very odd. Preferably, I would like to keep Times font throughout the whole file. How to change the default font (for both the word "CHAPTER" and "Ha Ha") in fncychap, please? Thank you! My code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  % font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  % chapter titles
  \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

  % needed for chapter toc
  \usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}

\begin{document}

  \mainmatter

  \chapter{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chapter font used by the `Sonny` style is simply the main font in Sans Serif family.

So, if you want to revert to the "normal" font, it suffices to define

```
\ChNameVar{\Large}
\ChTitleVar{\Large}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  % font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  % chapter titles
  \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
  \ChNameVar{\Large}
  \ChTitleVar{\Large}

  % needed for chapter toc
  \usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}

\begin{document}

  \mainmatter

  \chapter{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want it in boldface, change the definitions to

```
\ChNameVar{\Large\bfseries}
\ChTitleVar{\Large\bfseries}
```

and you will have the following result

[image]

It obviously work even if you have the main font as Times

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  % font
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  % chapter titles
  \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
  \ChNameVar{\Large}
  \ChTitleVar{\Large}

  % needed for chapter toc
  \usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}

  \usepackage{newtxtext}
  \usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

  \mainmatter

  \chapter{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

  \section{Ha Ha}

\end{document}
```

[image]